# Android Library Project Equivalent in Windows Phone 8

Tags: android, windows-phone-8, android-library

I have 2 Android apps that are 99% the same (different branding and a little bit of logic), so I have a library project that they both reference. This library project contains all of the UI and logic, and any differences between the apps are provided by overriding resources and extending my "`LibraryApplication`" (which itself extends `Application`).

I'm looking to port these apps to Windows Phone 8, and I'm wondering if there is a similar construct to help me mimic this pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Portable Class library for logic, however UI can't be shared in library. You can use files from the first project by adding them as a link to the second project. In case of UI it will be better to link all files without library at all.

Comment: What do you mean by link?

Comment: [Share code via link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714082%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).